# Why isnt echo $e->getMessage(); printing error message

Tags: php

I cant get this code to print the error message. I'm fairly new to php so go easy on me aha. I'm trying to make a register page for my website, feel free to request more of the code if it's required to help me.

```
try {
    //Username
    if(strlen($username) < 4) {
        throw new Exception('Username must be at least 4 Characters!');
    }
    if(strlen($username) > 16){
        throw new Exception('Username cannot be more than 15 characters!');
    }


    if(!ctype_alnum($username)) {
        throw new Exception('Username must only be letters or numbers');
    }

    // Password
    if(strlen($password) < 8) {
        throw new Exception('Password must be at least 8 characters!'); 
    }

    // email
    if(!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)){
        throw new Exception('Invalid Email!'); 
    }

    // secretcode
    if(strlen($secretcode) < 6) {
        throw new Exception('Secret Code is too short!'); 
    }

    if(strlen($secretcode) > 10) {
        throw new Exception('Secret Code is too long!'); 
    }

    //repassword
    if(strlen($password!=$repassword)) {
        throw new Exception('Passwords did not match');
    }


    // Submit to database
    echo 'ok';

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Can't get echo to print out error message

Comment: Not sure if it's the problem, but did you mean to have `$$password`?  Although `strlen($$password!=$repassword)` itself doesn't really make sense.

Comment: catch (Throwable $e) ?

Comment: @RambarunKomaljeet Uhh, just no. He's throwing an  `Exception`, and he can therefor catch it. http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: What exactly happens when you run the code? "Not working" is a very vague description.

Comment: @Qirel yes, but what if the exceptions are actually not getting thrown and its actually a 'throwable' error ( not sure if this is the right term) which is getting raised ?

Comment: My bad for confusion, i put at the bottom what happens when i execute the code

Comment: What does your code say? does it say 'ok'?

Comment: Some other notes: `username` can be 16 chars, but warning tells max of 15. `eregi()` is deprecated (and removed from php7?). You don't support mails with top level domains with more than 3 chars. Take a look at `filter_var()`.

Comment: Does nothing at all print? We're not seeing what you see on your screen, a good description is important.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue when working with classes. Just add this one line at the very top but after namespace declaration

```
namespace My\Workspace;
use Exception; //<-- this one

class Myclass 
{
    try {
        //your code
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

This is because if you don't use `use` php will go looking in `My\Workspace\Exception` which obviously doesn't exists and therefore the `catch` will never run.

If you don't wish to add the `use Exception;` declaration, a simple shortcut would be to add a backward slash in front of `Exception`

```
catch (\Exception $e)
```